# What is the difference between the web3 .js and web3Modal?

Tags: web3js

The docs state that:

- web3.js is a collection of libraries that allow you to interact with a local or remote ethereum node using HTTP, IPC or WebSocket
- Web3Modal is an easy-to-use library to help developers add support for multiple providers in their apps with a simple customizable configuration.

But besides one being a single library and the other being a collection of libraries, in practice, is one better than the other? Do they have different functionalities? Does web3.js contains Web3Modal?

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your objective as they are not the same.

`web3.js`

- as you already wrote, you will use the library **web3.js** to interact with the Ethereum blockchain. Web3.js can be used both in frontends and backends to read data from the blockchain or make transactions, and even deploy smart contracts to the blockchain.

`Web3Modal`

- the goal of **Web3Modal** is to give you a simple solution to support providers (you can read "wallet" here) like, eg, Metamask, Coinbase Wallet, etc. and let users connecting their  wallet to interact with your app. The lib let you extend providers support easily.